# 3x3 Involutory anti-commutative set of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

as in the case of [Pauli matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices#Pauli_vectors) for 2x2 [involutory matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involutory_matrix), I am looking for a set of 3x3 matrices named $\alpha_i$ (I do not know the size of the set, I assume 8 matrices?):

$$ \lbrace \alpha_i, \alpha_j \rbrace = 2 \delta_{i,j} I_3 $$

with $I_3$ the 3x3 identity matrix, $\delta_{i,j}$ Kronecker symbol, $ \lbrace A, B \rbrace = A B + B A$. So that means each $\alpha_i$ are involutory:

$$ \alpha_i^2 = I_3 $$

Do you know this set of matrices ? I am not familiar with linear algebra at this level.

**What I tried:**

I tried the spin-1 Pauli matrices (for a $l = 1$ angular momentum in quantum mechanics), obviously it does not work (not involutory). There is maybe a link to Clifford algebra, but after consulting the [gamma matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-dimensional_gamma_matrices), the issue is after the 4x4 well known Dirac matrices, they use a tensor product and the next ones are 8x8 gamma matrices. It does not fit unfortunately for my problem (where I need a 6x6 contaning my 3x3 $\alpha_i$ matrices)... Thank you for reading.

Comment: You can't do any better with $3 \times 3$ matrices than with $2 \times 2$ matrices, this is related to the representation theory of the Clifford algebras. The next up is $4 \times 4$ matrices.

Comment: ah ok, frustrating... Yes at a moment I found new involutory $\alpha_x$ and so on, but the anti commutativity rules was not satisfied. Ok thanks.